# Wordpress yoast seo разные заголовки для разных стран

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

Задача стоит в том, чтобы поменять заголовки для разных стран. Фильтр стран по IP я сделал. Так же хочу сделать условия, если страна 1, то заголовок такой, если 2 - другой и т.д. Стран 80 шт

Не хочется делать дубли 45 записей под 80 стран и всё ради заголовка. Но тут стоит вопрос в SEO, нужно, чтобы эти заголовки видел поисковик. Причём правильно, а не 80 шт на одной странице.

Как это будет или не будет работать?

1. Поисковик будет видеть только дефолтный заголовок.
2. Все заголовки
3. Той страны, в которой находится посетитель